# Elasticsearch - icu_folding and utf-8 searching

Tags: elasticsearch, utf-8

Even after hours of trying to understand Elastic search, I can not understand idea how to achieve the same results for searching text with special characters.

What I am doing wrong with icu_folding? How can I achieve, that results will be same for "Škoda" and "Skoda" same? Is it even possible?

https://github.com/pavoltravnik/examples/blob/master/elastic_search_settings.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the `icu_folding` token filter on the `name.sort` sub-field and not on the `name` field itself, so your queries need to be like this instead:

```
# 1 result as expected
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query": { "match": { "name.sort": "Škoda" } }
}'

# 0 results - I expected the same behaviour
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query": { "match": { "name.sort": "Skoda" } }
}'
```